# Batch File: Parsing a Registry Key whose name contains the % sign through the FOR command

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm having a problem using the reg query command to get a registry key value **through the for command** and saving the output to a variable.

For instance, the following works fine both outside and within the for command:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console" /v "ScreenBufferSize"
```

(Which displays the key to the current console window.)

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=: " %%V in (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console" /v "ScreenBufferSize"`) do set MyVar=%%V
```

(Which saves the value of the key to MyVar, which is what I want.)

But the problem is that the key whose value I want to obtain has the % sign on its name, and the **for** command seems to be unable to parse it, any each way I've tried. Escaping the % sign works for the first instance:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe" /v "ScreenBufferSize"
```

(Also displays the key to the current console window.)

But escaping it the same way in the for command fails:

```
 for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=: " %%V in (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe" /v "ScreenBufferSize"`) do set MyVar=%%V
```

producing the following output:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Please note the following:

- I'm using Windows7.
- I'm using the code in a batch file.
- I'm using both Delayed Expansion and Command Extensions.
- I don't want to create a temporary file to save the value to a variable.
- A key with the same name exists in both **HKCU\Console** and **HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe**, but it's the latter the one I need.

I've tried escaping the % sign in any way I could think of, and using pipe redirection to no avail. The for command is the best I could come up with, but it's not a must, all I want is that value saved on a variable!

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

V

Comment: is its output anything like this?:                           Lines:          9999
Columns:        237

Comment: what info does this give you?

Comment: The output (if the value of the key is properly extracted) is a hexadecimal REG_DWORD value, containing both the height (first 4 digits) and width (last 4 digits) of the console window that is running the batch file where the code is executed. Then I use hex2dec.exe to convert both values to decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys thank you for your answers,

After a lot of trying I found out a simple way to achieve the expected result, so I will be answering my own question, for those of you who have come upon the same obstacle.

I know that the for command is a bit tricky when manipulating variables, as it seems to discard escape signs after a variable is first used.

I found out that by setting a variable first where the percentage signs are escaped and then another one including the first one where the percentage signs are also escaped, works just fine. This means setting an additional variable, which I am not too happy about, but it is a small price to pay ;)

The 1st Example Works. When for expands the second variable, the first one is passed along, and the escaped percentage signs kept intact throughout the for command.

Example 1

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ParseKeyName=%%SystemRoot%%
set ParseKeyName2=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%ParseKeyName%%_system32_cmd.exe
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%V in ('reg query "%ParseKeyName2%" /v "ScreenBufferSize"') do set MyVar=%%V
echo %MyVar% is now the right value
```

The 2nd Example does not work, as the escaped percentage signs do not seem to be kept throughout the for processing, thus generating an error.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ParseKeyName=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%%%SystemRoot%%%%_system32_cmd.exe
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%V in ('reg query "%ParseKeyName%" /v "ScreenBufferSize"') do set MyVar=%%V
echo %MyVar% has not been set
```

I have also tried more than a dozen combinations of (!) (%) and (^) so that the for command would parse properly the variable but with no luck, so only the way given in the first example seems to work properly.

Thank you all for your insights!
V

edit: Oh, and it also works with the "usebackq" option, obviously ;)

Answer (score 1):

See how this goes - the issue is that the variable is set, so the solution is to blank the variable in a new copy of the environment, execute the command, and pass the variable back to the current environment.

The solution escaped me too, I tried all sorts of escaping - and another post today by @npocmaka used this technique in a similar issue.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "SystemRoot="
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=: " %%V in (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe" /v "ScreenBufferSize"`) do set "MyVar=%%V"
endlocal&set "myvar=%myvar%"
echo "%myvar%"
```

Here's a solution by @Endoro - it's not straight forward but it works here.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%V in ('reg query ^^"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\^%%SystemRoot^%%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe^" ') do echo %%V
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is quite tricky.

The main problem is to escape percents at the command line, as the FOR /F will start your command in a new cmd.exe context, so there are the cmd-line parser rules active, not the batch file rules.
And it's not possible to escape percents at the command line!

But foxidrive's second solution seems to escape the percents?
But it's not really escaping...
The parser sees `%%SystemRoot^%%` so it searches for a variable named `SystemRoot^` which isn't defined, then the caret is removed by the parser in the next phase, but only as the quotes are also escaped before.
So this solution works, but it's a bit complex and not bullet proof (try to set `set "SystemRoot^=xx"` before.

The first solution of foxidrive (to unset the variable first) is bullet proof here, but can't work for variable names like `%CD%` or `%time%`.

But if you can't escape percent signs, you could simply use a temporary variable to hold the string, as the parser will only once expand the percents.

```
set "myVar=%%SystemRoot%%"
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=: " %%V in (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%myVar%%_system32_cmd.exe" /v "ScreenBufferSize"`) do set "result=%%V"
echo %result%
```

Answer (score 0):

@Veronica_GB: Thank you for the research and the time you put into this; it was very helpful.

In case anyone else gets stuck, I think I've found another (marginally simpler) solution.  In my case, I was looking for FontSize, so I've used that below.

```
for /f "tokens=3 skip=2 delims= " %%a in (' "reg query hkcu\console\^%%systemroot^%%_system32_cmd.exe" -v fontsize ') do set fsize=%%a

echo FontSize: %fsize%
```